# code to add an extra selection to the menu editor

Tags: menus

I've given up looking for a plugin to achieve what I want (either they don't exist or I'm not using the correct search term) either way this leaves me with two options. Pay someone to make the changes to WP or do it myself. I'd prefer to do it myself but I admit that I'm a little nervous as I don't have much experience in .php coding although I am okay with html and css.

What I'm trying to achieve is a menu created from the data contained in a custom field of my product posts. Like this...
[image: proposed_WP_menu_mod]

What is the simplest way to achieve this? If there's a way that doesn't involve editing the WP GUI that just automatically adds the values from the custom field to a menu, then I'd be happy with that too.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The WooCommerce Brands plugin has this feature. 
https://woocommerce.com/products/brands/

[image]

It sounds like you would need to move your brands out of the custom field and into this plugin, so the effort will depend on how many product brands you have and whether you're willing to start over with this plugin.